# get one value from many same value in same column php

Tags: mysql

I want to take only one value from these matches values in one column and put it in select

```
SELECT company FROM `main_fore` ORDER BY `fore_id`
```

[image: Like this column in this picture]

Comment: Looks like you need `SELECT DISTINCT company`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `select distinct` or `group by`?

```
SELECT company
FROM main_fore 
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY MIN(fore_id)
```

Comment: what if I need two column

Comment: @murtadhadakhel . . . Well, if adding the second column to the `select` doesn't work, then ask *another* question.  New questions should be asked as questions rather than in comments.